# How to get cursor position relative to right side of browser window

Tags: css, dom

All:

I wonder how to get the cursor position relative to the right(include the width of scrollbar) side when the browser has a scrollbar.

I tried using window.innerWidth - event.clientX but this result not count the width of scrollbar in. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See if `window.outerWidth` works for you.

Comment: No problem, we all have those moments.

Comment: Thanks, funny thing is: the relative distance error gets bigger rather than smaller ToT

Comment: When are you capturing your click event? When clicking on a certain area of the screen? Is that area the entire inner window or a small portion of it?

Comment: From some posts, I learned that the innerwidth is the width of window with scrollbar, so it can not solve my problem, not to mention outterWidth. I finally use $(window).width as the content width value, it seems worked